# xcodebuild fails to create Archive due to SymLink error with Alamofire

Tags: iphone, alamofire, xcode8, xcodebuild

This is really winding me up now, all I am trying to do is an Xcode CLI build using the Xcode command line tools.

The flow is as follows:

- App Code is cloned from Git
- Info Plist and my own custom plist are generated and copied to project folder
- A new app icon set copied over into the assets directory
- Xcode Archive build is executed
- Xcode generate IPA build is executed

The issue is the Archive part keeps failing, and I cannot get it working. Annoyingly it works fine if I open the project in Xcode and Archive it through there, but that defeats the point of this automated process.

This is the command `xcodebuild -verbose -scheme EpicHRV1.1.0 -archivePath ios/app.xcarchive archive`

And here is the constant resultant error. I really can't figure out what its complaining about, I mean, it says something to do with Alamofire and missing modules, but why would this work in Xcode but not the command line?

`Command failed: xcodebuild -verbose -scheme EpicHRV1.1.0 -archivePath ios/app.xcarchive archive
2017-01-07 20:24:04.255 xcodebuild[43780:2460638]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-11754/DVTFoundation/Utilities/DVTFileSystemUtilities.mm:142
Details:  lstat('/Users/Justin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EpicHR-dgdtmzwowkyxgkfzmizhuhiaxkrt/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/EpicHRV1.1.0/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Alamofire.framework/Modules') failed with errno 2 (No such file or directory)
Function: DVTRecursiveMkdirResult dvt_recursiveMkdir_returningErrorString(NSString *__strong, NSString *__autoreleasing *)
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f90e8ae7cf0>{number = 7, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
** ARCHIVE FAILED **`

Here is another lovely error which also randomly appears, but not every time...

`The following build commands failed:
        SymLink /Users/Justin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EpicHR-dgdtmzwowkyxgkfzmizhuhiaxkrt/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/EpicHRV1.1.0/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Alamofire.framework /Users/Justin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EpicHR-dgdtmzwowkyxgkfzmizhuhiaxkrt/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/EpicHRV1.1.0/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Alamofire.framework`

And another error that sometimes appears. With all of the above the only consistent thing is Alamofire is mentioned in the error..

`The following build commands failed:
        Strip /Users/Justin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EpicHR-dgdtmzwowkyxgkfzmizhuhiaxkrt/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/EpicHRV1.1.0/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire`

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Tobol Actually I did in the end, I'll share it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it with the following commands:

```
xcodebuild -scheme EpicHRV1.1.0 -archivePath ../ios/app.xcarchive archive

xcrun xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist exportPlist.plist -archivePath ../ios/app.xcarchive -exportPath ../ios/ipa/
```

Comment: @ NodeJustin, Were you able to find out the reason behind 'SymLink' issue ?. And does this command fixed your SymLink issue as well ?

Comment: I never figured out the reason, but that build command above worked for (at the time, I haven't touched it for a while I'll admit)

Comment: Thanks NodeJustin, I figured out that in my case 'SymLink' issue was caused because I was using CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR option in my build command. Although why this option was causing the error is still unknown.